# Why does scipy.interpolate.interp1d() tell me my xnew value is out of range?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate data in Python but it's just not working.

The specific problem is as follows: I have BminV colour data for a sample of stars (around 70 of them). I have generated these values for theoretical black-body emitters as well, by interpolation.

```
#BminV is the data from the stars.
temperatures = np.arange(1000.0, 80000.0, 50.0)
#I generate for each of these temperatures a BminV colour. these are stored in BminVblack.
f = interpolate.interp1d(BminVblack, temperatures, kind='cubic')
print f(BminV)
```

For each and every value of BminV this returns an error saying it's out of the interpolation range. I thought I'd check these ranges

```
print np.min(BminVblack), np.max(BminVblack)
print np.min(BminV), np.max(BminV)
```

This works out to have the BminVblack range as -.38 to 3.2, and the BminV range from -.36 to 1.8. Why does it still say that some values of BminV are out of range for the interpolation?

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: Can you check that `BminVblack` is a monotonically increasing array? It is monotonically increasing if `np.all(np.diff(BminVblack)>0)` evaluates to `True`. If it not monotonically increasing, an 'out of range' error can be raised.

Comment: @flebool I changed BminVblack and temperatures to go the other way ([::-1]) and now it works properly. The results are pretty reasonable as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that `BminVblack` is a monotonically increasing array.

It is monotonically increasing if `np.all(np.diff(BminVblack)>0)` evaluates to `True`.

If it is not monotonically increasing, an 'out of range' error can be raised. The same happens if the input array is monotonically decreasing, as was your case.